# "expr-tokens.l" , line 52:unrecognized %option : reentrant

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have a file named "expr-tokens.l" or a "lex" file that when I try to parse using "flex expr-tokens.l" command, gives me the error ["expr-tokens.l" , line 52:unrecognized %option : reentrant].

Parsing this file will generate a ".c" file that has the definition of the methods that I am trying to link to my main program.  I do not understand if this is the Bison version problem, I am using Bison 2.5.4 version or something else.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show line 52 of the file, and preferably the surrounding lines?

Answer (score 1):

The `%option reentrant` syntax is for Flex, the scanner generator (not Bison, which works at a higher level with the grammar).

Make sure your Flex version is up to date.

Comment: I am using Flex version 2.5.4a for windows that is the latest version available foe WINDOWS that I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you are using the old version from GnuWin32.

With this one it works: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/